# VBCSCompiler.exe has stopped working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm testing a simple WPF desktop project in Visual Studio 2015 after I've installed .Net 4.6.2.

Every time I build I get a couple of messages saying "VBCSCompiler.exe has stopped working" with the following details (translated to English)

```
Problem Signing:
   Problem event name: CLR20r3
   Problem Signing 01: VBCSCompiler.exe
   Problem Signing 02: 1.3.1.60616
   Problem Signing 03: c7726f5a
   Problem Signing 04: System.Configuration
   Problem Signing 05: 4.6.1590.0
```

I've already deactivated UI Debugging and Diagnostic Tools and the AntiVirues and I've also tried starting `devenv /safemode`

This happens even if I start a **new** C# project > Windows > Classic Desktop > WPF Application and I build it *without any changes*.

Answer (score 1):

I've started the vbcscompiler from the VS Build command prompt as suggested from [microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2947195)

I've seen it crashes with a message related to the machine.config (I edited it in fact). So that was the issue.

Starting again Visual Studio as admin and commenting out the problematic line from machine.config did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue for me with Visual Studio 2015, building a C# MVC web application. The problem turned out to be a bad section in the machine.config. I removed that section and everything started working again.

The only way I figured this out was because another application (terminals) suddenly quit working at the same time, but at least included this helpful exception message:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 289)